# How to change the Id mention in html , Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="container" id="c0">
  <div class="image" id="i0">
    <div class="info">
      <h3><a href="pressure.html" target="_blank">Atmospheric Pressure </a></h3>
      <p id="node13/pressure"> </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="story" id="s0">
    <div class="info">
      <h3><a href="humidity.html" target="_blank">Humidity</a></h3>
      <p id="node13/humidity"> value </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="c1">
  <div class="image" id="i1">
    <div class="info">
      <h3><a href="voltage.html" target="_blank">Battery Voltage</a></h3>
      <p id="node13/voltage"> Parameters use to measure Battery Voltage are : </p>
```

... And so on ...

So is there any way I can change the id dynamically like creating any variable 
`var x = "node13"` since this value `node13` or `node14` will be coming from backend, and every-time value is updated I need to change the node value.

Comment: Didn't understood your question. What you need exactly? i understood, you want to update <p id="node13/humidity"> value </p> this? what value you are getting dynamically? is that value or  id value which is node13 or node14

Comment: Yes you can but for what purpose? Are you sure this is not a XY problem? It sounds you are trying to fix something possibly at the wrong end, maybe? I find most of the time identifiers are irrelevant and not needed for generated code. I usually use `data-id="story"` or `data-id="container"` etc.. That way I can bind events and then just use positional traversal selectors within each set as needed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with id updates?

Comment: @user3599302 
I am getting node 13 or node 14 from my backend. 

i want to replace every-time
 <p id="node13/humidity">
or
<p id=node14/humidity"> 

So is there any way !

Comment: @Nope  Actually this data is coming from mqtt , and it will show the live value of that particular node , so thats why i am using like id.

Comment: Is humidity is constant in all the div's ?

Comment: @user3599302 yes it is constant in all div , just the node value is changing everytime

Comment: @AyushKumar Why do you need to switch the id? "Hacks" like this usually indicate an issue is not addressed and worked around instead at the wrong end. What other process needs you to change the identifier and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].setAttribute("id", "newID");
```

Or in JQuery you can use .attr() method
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: What is this H1 [0]

Comment: @AyushKumar The part you are interested in is `.setAttribute("id", "newID")` the selector is an example in the answer but you just use your own selector off course.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the ID dynamically with jQuery.

```
$('#node13/voltage').attr('id','node14/voltage');
```